# How much memory should a React Native iOS app reasonably use?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

My app generally runs between 40MB - 250MB (lots of video components, some animation).

The app feels very fast in the simulator (when debug is off), but I'm worried I should be concerned about the memory usage.

Is this high? Is there a general standard people aim for when considering memory usage?